# Find the cardinality of the set of all obtuse triangles on Cartesian plane

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Find the cardinality of the set of all obtuse triangles on Cartesian plane

I have attempted this problem, but I am not sure whether or not my solution is correct.

Let's represent an obtuse triangle as $(x,y,z) \in (R^2) \times (R^2) \times (R^2)$ where $x, y, z$ are the vertices of the triangle. Now, since this triangle is obtuse, we have that $(d(x,y))^2 + (d(y,z))^2 < (d(x,z))^2$. Now, let's fix $x = (0,0)$ and $y = (1,1)$. Let $z = (0, z_1)$. By doing this, we get this inequality: 
$$2 + z^2 < 1 + (z-1)^2 \iff 0 < z < 1$$
Now, consider these two sets: 
$$\{x\} \times \{y \} \times (0,1)$$ (The set of all obtuse triangles with two vertices fixed at $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ and the third one fixed on the x - axis, on the segment $(0,1)$. The cardinality of this set is continuum. Thus, the cardinality of the set in question is bounded form below by continuum. It's also bounded from above by the cardinality of $(\mathbb R^2)^3$ Thus, it's cardinality is continuum.

Comment: You can parametrize them instead by the vertices on the small side that appears first counterclockwise, the angle ($>\pi/2$) and the length of the other small side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this reasoning looks convincing.

The first part is a bit complex for what it achieves. Basically what you want to do is just to show continuum many *different* obtuse triangles. But all you need to say there is that there are continuum many values the obtuse angle can have -- namely every number between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$ -- and for each of those angles **there is at least one triangle with that angle**.

It would be an extremely skeptical reader who would need you to speak about particular coordinates to justify the bolded step here.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way for the lower bound: take an arbitrary obtuse triangle, then the family of triangles constructed from it by a [homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation) of ratio $\,\lambda \ne 0\,$ centered at the origin (a) contains only triangles similar to the original one, thus obtuse, and (b) has the cardinality or $\mathbb{R}$ since triangles corresponding to different $\lambda$ are different.